# boostrap sticky footer and two responsive columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the footer.

On the side I have two columns. These columns are set to auto top margin.

As an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jewelsjacobs/kSgE6/light/.

If you change the resolution so that the columns fall under her foot overlaps with pictures instead of being constantly on the bottom of the page.

Example: [image]
Normal view:
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="pl">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $.backstretch("img/bg.jpg");
</script>
<style>
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "AvanteGarde";
        font-size: 70px;
    }
    header p{
        font-family: "AvanteGarde";
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family:"AvanteGarde";
        src: url('font/font2.ttf');
    }
    .col-centered{

        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
        height: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family:"AvanteGarde";
    }
    .ng{
        color: #3a8c03;
        font-family: "AvanteGarde";
        font-size: 40px;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
     }

    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .container-fluid{
        height:60%;
        display:table;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .row-fluid {height: 100%; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}

    .centering {
        float:none;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    header{
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

</style>
<header>
    <h1><label style="color: #3a8c03"> F.P.H.U </label> <label style="color: #254c0b"> Darmont</label></h1>
    <p style="color: #3a8c03">KOMINKI - OCZYSZCZALNIE - DORADZTWO - SERWIS</p>
</header>

<div class="container-fluid" style="width: 900px; margin: auto;">
    <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-centered">
                <img src="img/oczyszczalnie.png"   class="img-responsive center-block">
                <p class="ng">oczyszczalnie</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-centered" style="padding-left: 120px">
                <img src="img/kominki.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
                <p class="ng">kominki</p>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <p>Skontaktuj sie z nami i zapytaj o produkty</p>
    <p>nr. tel: 924 456 256  e-mail: aaa@sga.com</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your jsfiddle reference is pointing to a different problem than the one mentioned above.

Comment: yes, jsfiddle only to the two images have always auto margin, does not affect the footer

Comment: if you wanna footer to be _constantly on the bottom of the page_ (not screen), just do it: 1. remove `position: absolute` line from .footer rules; 2. wrap `<footer>...</footer>` into `<div class='row'></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's good sample code on the [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) for a sticky footer,
[working example](http://www.bootply.com/panchroma/70755)